# Allow everyone to access in Yii2 controller

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a project where I am implementing an existing Yii project on top.  The issue is the new Yii project has its own user login and authentication.  I want to allow anyone access by global rights or just remove all of the authentication all together and use my own page authentication.

In my site controller I have modified to:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
       'access' => [
           'class' => AccessControl::className(),
           'rules' => [
               [
                   'allow' => true,
                   'roles' => ['?'],
               ],
               // ...
           ],
       ],
    ];
}
```

I have removed the `actionLogin()` and `actionLogout()` from this site controller as well but am still sent to the logon page.

- `*`: any user, including both anonymous and authenticated users.
- `?`: anonymous users.
- `@`: authenticated users.

This is what I have added:
https://github.com/gugoan/economizzer

```
public function behaviors()
    {
      return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::classname(),
            'only'  => ['index','create','update','delete','view','target','accomplishment','overview','performance'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['*']
                ],
            ]
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
   }
```

Comment: Please share full configuration of `AccessControl` behavior. Later rules overrides former, so it is important to know what is in `// ...` place.

Comment: In the first sitecontroler the //... is exactly that.  Nothing.

Comment: are you saying that you have added another `app` like `frontend` into your existing project?

Comment: No this is the only app.  The other is straight php and some sql.

Comment: Check where this controller is extends from.

Answer (score 1):

There is no role `*`, you need to use:

```
'roles' => ['?', '@']
```